# CFArrayGetValueAtIndex not returning aything

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays

I have an *extremely* simple code snippet to get the application support directory of a use. Problem is, it doesn't work! I get the values in a `CFArrayRef` (because I want to use C code since I will use this snippet in a C++ application later) and try to get the first string in there using `CFArrayGetValueAtIndex()`. I convert the returned `void*` to a `char*` using a C-style cast and attempt to output it using `printf()`, but nothing gets outputted! Can anyone explain why? I've looked online through the documentation for `CFArray` and tried to google the issue, but came up with nothing. Any help would be really appreciated!

Code:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <typeinfo>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    CFArrayRef array = \
      (CFArrayRef)NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                        NSApplicationSupportDirectory, 
                        NSUserDirectory, 
                        YES);
    char* string = (char*)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(array, 0);
    printf("string: %s\n", string);
    [pool drain];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you converting it to a `char*`? The resulting array from `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()` contains `CFStringRef`s, not `char*`s.

Try using `CFShow((CFTypeRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(array, 0));`

Comment: oh wow, now I feel ridiculous! I assume `CFStringRef`s are equivalent to `NSString`s, right? So I'll have to use a method that converts them to `char*`s most likely. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @rcplusplus: Why are you even using `CFArray` here? Why are you doing these casts?

Comment: Because I'm writing C++ code, so I don't want to use Objective-C classes. If I wanted to use Objective-C with my C++, I'd have to make the file .mm extension, which would mean I couldn't compile the thing on windows.